# How can i position this button under my paragraph correctly?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a tile on my website that flips over when i hover over it. On the back of the first i attempted putting a button. The button hangs off of the bottom and im not quite sure how i can get it below the paragraph i have on the back of the tile. Also, i can't get the header of the tile centered. I tried using

```
text-align:center;
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/loserman778/HUu7E/1/) the code i'm writing up. So if you run it and hover over the first black tile you'll see the text 'eternally rustled'. That's the problematic tile. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to wrap them in a div and that div needs to have text-align:center; you can't add text-align:center on a object you are trying to center.

Comment: Okay, simply enough thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have your fix! Using what you gave us I just added two things to the "btile" portion of the CSS so it looks like the one below:

```
#btile {
    width:350px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and to fix your header problem, I simply added width to the code below:

```
.webname {
    width: 350px;//I added this
    font:800 17px/17px"open sans";
    color:#333;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:1px dashed #888;
    z-index:50;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Where does the width come from? It's the size of your picture! Just make sure the div width is the same size of the picture and you're set. Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUu7E/4/) that can show you exactly what I did! Let me know if it doesn't work! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You're solution to the header worked great and it's centered, but the only problem is, is that the button is hanging off of the bottom of the tile.

Comment: Do you want it in the tile?

Comment: Yes, would you know how i could go about doing that?

Comment: It's pretty unconventional because you have to use 'position' and position is never really a safe way to make sure everything stays consistent across all browsers but this would be your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/HUu7E/6/

Comment: That did the trick. I fixed some prefixes and that seemed to make it work in both chrome and firefox. Thanks for your help!